# being polynomial is a local property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

prove that being polynomial on $\mathbb{R}$ is a local property.it means if f is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that equals restriction of a polynomial in a nbhd of every real number then it must be a polynomial.

i really don't know how to approach this as a topology exercise,may be it has a solution in real analysis,...i don't know.

any solution or hint are welcomed even if they are real analysis not topology.

thank you

Comment: Read R.P.Boas, Jr. _A Primer of Real Functions_ (1981), p. 65. Can it help ?

Comment: Ewan's answer is excellent. But in case you already know that if a smooth function $f$ has the property that for $x\in\Bbb R$ there is an $n$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ then $f$ is a polynomial (a theorem that follows from the Baire Category Theorem), you reach the same conclusion.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to use the basic fact that if two polynomials coincide on an inifinite set, they are identical (this is because a nonzero polynomial can have only finitely many roots).

For any $x\in{\mathbb R}$, there is a polynomial $P_x$ such that $f$ coincides with $P_x$ on a neighborhood of $x$. Show first that $P_x$ is unique, using the basic fact. It follows very easily that the map $x\mapsto P_x$ is locally constant on $\mathbb R$, so it must be globally constant since $\mathbb R$ is connected.

Comment: sorry i can't understand this:"It follows very easily that the map x↦Px is locally constant on R, so it must be globally constant since R is connected." explain more please

Comment: @user115608 which part do you need more explanations about ? The first "The map is locally constant" or the second "so it must be globally constant since R is connected" ?

Comment: i thank you a lot and i'm sorry to say:both of them

Comment: About the first : for every $x$, there is an open neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ such that $f$ coincides with $P_x$ on $V_x$. For any $y\in V_x$, $W=V_x\cap V_y$ is another open neighborhood of $y$, and $f$ coincides with coincides with both $P_x$ and $P_y$ on it, so $P_x=P_y$. This shows that $P_y=P_x$ for any $y\in V_x$.

Comment: About the second : take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_constant_function

Comment: you mean if f has two values then preimages of that values are a separation for $\mathbb{R}$ yeah?

Comment: @ Ewan Delanoy thank you very much.can you please help me with this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844382/a-topological-space-is-the-union-of-its-irreducible-components

Comment: @ Ewan Delanoy thank you very much.can you please help me with this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844382/a-topological-space-is-the-union-of-its-irreducible-components