# a topological space is the union of its irreducible components

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

if we define  irreducible component of a topological space $X$ as the maximal closed irreducible subset of $X$,prove that we can write $X$ as the union of its  irreducible components.

how to approach it?

thanks.

Comment: First, your statement is incorrectly worded. You cannot say "the irreducible component” of $X$ because there may be several irreducible components. Are you trying to self-learn topology ? Is this homework ?

Comment: The (A) maximal closed subset of $X$ is obviously $X$ itself. Something is missing in your question.

Comment: you are right i'm taking a course in general topology & i have many hard exercise to deal with

Comment: What is an irreducible subset?

Comment: we call $X$ an irreducible topological space if we can't write it as a union of two closed proper subset

Comment: You are always leaving something out of your statements. (For example, with your definition the closed interval $[0,1]$ is reducible, because $[0,1]=[0,1/2]\cup[1/2,1]$.) This carelessness prevents you from solving mathenatical problems.

Comment: The proof, using Zorn's lemma, is [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/004W).

Answer (score -1):

Outline of proof:

1. If $Y$ and $Z$ are irreducible components of $X$, then either $Y=Z$ or $Y\cap Z=\varnothing$.
2. Every point $x\in X$ is contained in some irreducible component.

..........

n. PROFIT!

---

Hint: $n=3$.

Comment: i know 1. & 2. but i don't know what do mean "n"?because the number of irreducible components can be infinite

Comment: n=3 means that having 1 and 2, already at the third step of your reasoning you can conclude that $X$ is the disjoint union of irreducible components. Indeed, take the union of all irreducible components. By 1, it is disjoint. By 2, every point $x\in X$ lies in this union, and hence the union coincides with $X$.

Comment: i said i know the reason of 1. & 2. but i made mistake.can you tell me the reasons briefly?

Comment: 1. If $Y,Z$ are irreducible, then $Y\cup Z$ has to be reducible. If $Y\ne Z$ and $Y\cap Z\ne\varnothing$, prove that either $Y$ or $Z$ is reducible in this case. 2. Exercise.

Comment: if space is hausdorff i knew 2. but what can be said without this condition?

Comment: For each $x\in X$, $\overline{\{x\}}$ is irreducible. (If $\overline{\{x\}}=A\sqcup B$ with $A$ and $B$ closed, then $A$ or $B$ contains $x$ and hence, being closed, contains $\overline{\{x\}}$.) Prove that the union of all irreducible sets containing $x$ is irreducible.

Comment: ok i proved that the union of all irreducible sets containing $x$ is irreducible but how can i say it is a component?

Comment: Because this set (denote it by $W$) is the maximal irreducible set containing $x$: every irreducible set containing $x$ is cointained in it. Now if $V\supset W$ is irreducible, then $V\ni x$ and hence $V\subset W$. Thus, $W$ is a maximal irreducible set.

Comment: oh yes!what stupid question! so the proof is complete am i right?

Comment: exactly. The proof is complete.

Comment: Apologies that this comment is 8 years after the fact, but it is not the case that the intersection of irreducible components must be empty. However, it is certainly true that no irreducible component can contain another irreducible component. Surely we just need 2 in your logic to conclude the result?